# Get Python Dependency Versions with pyproject.toml

Tags: python, installation, pip, pyproject.toml

Let's say I have a local package that contains the following `pyproject.toml` file:

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "setuptools>=42",
    "wheel",
    "cython",
    "oldest-supported-numpy",
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

Then, I build and install the package via:

```
python -m pip install .
```

And the package was successfully built (with `pyproject.toml` and installed and the tests all passed. However, as I understand it, since there is a `pyproject.toml` file, all of the dependencies (listed in `requires`) are installed in an isolated environment by `pip` before the build occurs. Is there any way to figure out which package versions for those dependencies are installed inside of the isolated environment?

Answer (score 0):

I learned that you can have `pip` print out the build dependency versions with

```
python -m pip install . -v
```